# Can't open gnome-control-center in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

I used to be able to open Settings from the applications icon. Now when I try to load the icon, nothing happens. When I type `gnome-control-center` in Terminal, I get the following error:

```
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18: undefined symbol:
```

I have tried a variety of updates and upgrades suggested on other posts.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you still get the eroor if you try to open gnome shell extensions with https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: @zx485 Please don't use blockquotes for Terminal outputs. Code blocks should be used instead.

Comment: What happens if you reinstall `libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18` by running the following in Terminal: `sudo apt install --reinstall libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18`?

Comment: Thank you so much pomsky that worked!